# Elastic search pagination starting with a particular document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic search to show a paginated list of products in a grid view in a mobile app. Now the user can scroll through the list and click on any product to view the details.

Now the detail view also supports scrolling through the products via swipe left and right. So for the detail view, I want to fetch paginated results from elastic search starting from a particular product.

For now I am calculating the index of the product in list view and then doing the math to fetch that particular page and scroll to the index.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How many products are there?

Comment: More than 10 thousand, I have to make paginated calls to the server

Comment: @Sunny Do you offer multiple sorting mechanisms or is there only one default sort?

Comment: There are multiple filter and sort conditions available on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) to get paginated results for your search query.

Alternatively, you can use the [search_after api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) which seems to perform better for large number of results but it is available only for 7.x+ elastic versions.

Comment: The scroll API doesn't allow you to paginate the way you expect. Also, the Scroll API should not be used in a real-time context, it's more intended for batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally certain — I haven't tested it myself — but I think the suggestion of using the [search after API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) is the way to go.

You need to use something like the [point in time feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html), which is what the search after uses. Without it, you have no guarantee that the data in the database aren't changing. If the data change, then your search result may change. If that changes, then what comes "next" also changes, and that may no longer correspond to what you want.

E.g., if you currently have 10 search results and your item of interest is at index 5, if someone adds a document that moves your point of interest to index 6, then naïvely asking for the next item would return the same thing!

The point in time feature creates a snapshot of the database at a moment in time, so you don't have to worry about new or modified documents messing things up.

As an aside, using the point in time feature at scale is probably (again, making educated guesses here) not a very good idea. Elasticsearch has to keep a mini-snapshot of the whole database (!) every time you call that for the duration.

You're probably better off limiting the number of items people can page through to something large but manageable, and then reloading a new page if someone gets to the end. If you pull 500 products initially and someone gets to the end (which seems unlikely to me a priori), you could re-issue the search paged forward 500 items, deduplicate at the boundary and no one will be the wiser.